# fatal: cannot create directory at 'node_modules/Base64': Permission denied, During git checkout master

Tags: git

I have a feature branch that is about 50 commits ahead of the master branch. I wanted to checkout master branch to make a small edit and push that out. Although as soon as I type `git checkout master` I was prompted to commit my changes, all of a sudden git had un-staged all the commits I had made and was asking me to commit them before checking out master.

Essentially reseting my feature branch back to what master looked like in the first place. I committed and hard reset back to my most recent commit on that branch as to not lose all my work. Is there some kind of error going on since I have added and removed many files?

EDIT MORE Info

I deleted a node_module browserify but the module is on master. 
On my feature branch everything is added and committed. This is the error I get right after I type `git checkout master`.

`error: unable to create symlink node_modules/.bin/JSONStream: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink node_modules/.bin/acorn: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink node_modules/.bin/browser-pack: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink node_modules/.bin/browserify: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink node_modules/.bin/deps-sort: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink node_modules/.bin/insert-module-globals: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink node_modules/.bin/miller-rabin: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink node_modules/.bin/module-deps: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink node_modules/.bin/sha.js: Permission denied
error: unable to create symlink node_modules/.bin/umd: Permission denied
fatal: cannot create directory at 'node_modules/Base64': Permission denied`

Right after I do this, (btw I am working on webstorm so it shows me my version control in a panel), my version control shows all my commits are not in red and need to "add them" but this is not adding my commits its adding the inverse. So getting rid of all my commits.

Also I am working on a vagrant box on mac.

Comment: `git checkout` refuses to proceed if you have local uncommited changes in files that `checkout` would need to modify. It does not "unstage" any commit (which actually would not make sense, "stage/unstage" happens before commits). If you want help, you'll need to show *exactly* what you did, what you obtained, and what you expected.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy I made edits to my question with more information. Is there a way to uncommit one singular commit? I am about 30 commits ahead of where I removed the node module.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo` is your problem, not the solution. Don't use `sudo` for development-related tasks. Ever. Don't use `sudo git ...` ever either. You don't need admin permission to work and use Git. Git is not meant to be used as root.

Your problem is that you probably used `sudo` in the past, hence you ran a command as `root` and you created some files that belong to `root`. You can check this with e.g. `ls -l` or `find . -user 0`. Then, the next time you tried to modify these files belonging to root, you don't have permission to do it (see the error message: `Permission denied`).

The actual solution is to give back the files to your normal user, using `chown`, for which you will need to use `sudo` one *last* time.

Comment: This was exactly my issue. I ended up running `sudo chown -Rv <username> <project>` to reset the whole thing. Now I don't have any locked files. It was a pain and must have used sudo at some time while starting up with the project. Thank you.

Comment: never knew that because of sudo you will be stopped doing something, everytime something says permission denied sudo does it but this was the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

Run command `ls -l` — it will show all the files and folders with the users permission. So, you can notice that your node_modules folder will be having root permission instead of normal user permission. That is why it is expecting 'sudo' for creating files inside `node_modules`.

To fix that run

```
sudo chown -R $USER node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I needed to use `sudo git checkout master` I have never had to use this before to checkout master. If anyone can explain why this works please add an answer and I will mark that as the answer.